# CSV Reader Removing Double Quotes from First Field

Tags: python, csvreader

I have a file which contains a tab delimited header and line like so:

```
ID  Field1
test1   "A","B"
```

Here's my parsing script.

```
with open(dataFile) as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter='\t'):
        print(line)
```

And the output:

```
['ID', 'Field1']
['test1', 'A,"B"']
```

I can't figure out why it's stripping the double quotes on the first quoted item of the second field. I've tried different dialects and settings for csv reader with no success.

Comment: have you tried to give define a dtype for your 'string' columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell the `csv.reader` to ignore quoting, via the [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) option:

```
with open(dataFile) as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
['ID', 'Field1']
['test1', '"A","B"']
```

Comment: Thanks! Went with this as the solution, as it ignores the quoting rather than change it

Comment: @YTsaL FWIW, you can turn the data in the second column into a tuple of strings like `('A', 'B')` by using `line[1] = ast.literal_eval(line[1])`.

Answer (score 3):

The default quote char for csv reader is double quote so it automatically removes them. Changing it to something like '|' will solve your problem. You can do it like this:

```
with open(dataFile) as tsv:
    for line in csv.reader(tsv, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|'):
        print(line)
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar:

**Dialect.quotechar**

A one-character string used to quote fields containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain new-line characters. It defaults to '"'.

EDIT:

Also you can use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`option to disable quoting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are delimiting a tab and not actually splitting on the comma, I would change your code to reflect this.

Comment: Just to add to this: It seems like you are only bringing in one field. Your program doesn't see a tab so it assumes there is only one field on that first line. (please mark Nick's answer as correct if it solves your problem)

Comment: Where this answer helps the post? He's not asking about the comma

Comment: Nick, to Joao's point, perhaps you could show the line of code that should change, along with the suggested changes.